# Use multiple highlight colors on QTreeWidgetItems in a QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyside2, qtreewidget

I am trying to create a QTreeWidget that uses a single highlight color for all but the last selection.

I am able to change ALL the colors using the setPalette from the QTreeWidget but that only applies to the QTreeWidget and not the QTreeWidgetItems. There is no setPalette on the QTreeWidgetItems

I even tried using style sheet but again it only applies to the QTreeWidget. This method is a little painful in my actual code as I have multiple columns and branches. Currently, commented out in my code

I know I need a signal but to get the selection just don't know how to highlight them differently

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui

class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Test Dialog")
        self.setMinimumWidth(200)

        self.tree = TreeWidget()

        # Change all the highlighted items to the same color
        # palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        # palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QtGui.QColor(93, 93, 93))
        # self.tree.setPalette(palette)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'black']
        parent = self.tree
        for color in colors:
            parent = TreeWidgetItem(parent, color)

        self.tree.expandAll()

class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setIndentation(10)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.header().resizeSection(1, 28)
        self.header().swapSections(1, 0)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        css = """
            QTreeView::item:selected
                {
                    background-color: grey;
                }
            """
        # self.setStyleSheet(css)
        delegate = MyDelegate(None, self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)

class TreeWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, label):
        super(TreeWidgetItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText(0, label)

        self.lockBox_cb = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

        self.treeWidget().setItemWidget(self, 1, self.lockBox_cb)


class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent, tree):
        super(MyDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tree = tree

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        column = index.column()
        row = index.row()
        item = self.tree.itemFromIndex(index)
        currentItem = self.tree.currentItem()

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.fillRect(option.rect, brush)

        if column == 0:
            if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:

                if id(currentItem) == id(item):
                    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(102, 40, 178, 255))
                else:
                    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(226, 131, 255, 255))
                option.palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)



                option_copy = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
                option_copy.rect.setLeft(0)
                option_copy.backgroundBrush = brush

                self.tree.style().drawPrimitive(QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_PanelItemViewItem, option_copy, painter)




            super(MyDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    d = TestDialog()
    d.show()
```

I updated the code to reflect one of my many attempts. The results have always been the same. The color does change after additional selections but partially shows the old color until I click on a different UI. Only, then does the color fills the whole row

[image: Colors before GUI is refreshed]

Once the gui refreshes, the colors are correct

[image]

Comment: I added QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate that allows different colors of the row but does not update correctly

Comment: Never mind the space on the left side. Those are check boxes. In my real code you can see the color around the check box. That is why I setLeft option_copy to 0 to color the entire row.

Comment: I do not reproduce the first image, maybe it is a theme of styles, try `app.setStyle("fusion")`, what is the output of `print(app.style().metaObject().className())`?

Comment: I am using Maya's mayapy.exe as my interpreter. I failed to mentioned that. The style is QadskDarkFlatUIStyle, when running ```print self.style().metaObject().className()```

Comment: use `QApplication.instance().setStyle("fusion")`. That problem is generated by the style that Maya uses.

Comment: I will look into that. But, I am unfamiliar where to set the style in my example as I am not using QApplication. I tried in the "__main__"

d.setStyle('Fusion')


```  PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.setStyle(str)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.setStyle(PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyle) # ```

```d.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))``` doesn't change anything

Comment: use `from PySide2 import QtWidgets` `QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: I got the same results as my first image but with my funky white and black Maya window. Colors are still not refreshing correctly

Comment: try with: `d.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory::create("fusion"))`

Comment: It didn't visible change the style and had the same off color results.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Curious if the results are the same in a normal Python interpreter. I have to find time to install one. Then get pyqt to work. That will take some time. If anyone can confirm that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Its the Branch color that is not being changed. if you use a style sheet and set it to what the background color is you wont get the highlight happening past the item itself. This worked for me.

For Example:

```
QTreeView::branch {
    background-color: grey;
}
```